# Running something in a method takes much more depending on the data types

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

## Introduction

Today I found a weird behaviour in python while running some experiments with exponentiation and I was wondering if someone here knows what's happening. In my experiments, I was trying to check what is faster in python `int**int` or `float**float`. To check that I run some small snippets, and I found a really weird behaviour.

## Weird results

My first approach was just to write some for loops and prints to check which one is faster. The snipper I used is this one

```py
import time
# Run powers outside a method
ti = time.time()
for i in range(EXPERIMENTS):
    x = 2**2
tf = time.time()
print(f"int**int took {tf-ti:.5f} seconds")
ti = time.time()
for i in range(EXPERIMENTS):
    x = 2.**2.
tf = time.time()
print(f"float**float took {tf-ti:.5f} seconds")
```

After running it I got

```
int**int took 0.03004 
float**float took 0.03070 seconds
```

Cool, it seems that data types do not affect the execution time. However, since I try to be a clean coder I refactored the repeated logic in a function `power_time`

```py
import time
# Run powers in a method
def power_time(base, exponent):
    ti = time.time()
    for i in range(EXPERIMENTS):
        x = base ** exponent
    tf = time.time()
    return tf-ti
print(f"int**int took {power_time(2, 2):.5f} seconds")
print(f"float**float took {power_time(2., 2.):5f} seconds")
```

And what a surprise of mine when I got these results

```
int**int took 0.20140 seconds
float**float took 0.05051 seconds
```

The refactor didn't affect a lot the `float` case, but it multiplied by ~7 the time required for the `int` case.

## Conclusions and questions

Apparently, running something in a method can slow down your process depending on your data types, and that's really weird to me.

Also, if I run the same experiments but change ** by * or + the weird results disappear, and all the approaches give more or less the same results

Does someone know why is this happening? Am I missing something?

Comment: Try altering the first snippet to also have a base and exponent variable that you initially set and then change before the float loop. I would expect that to behave identically to your second snippet. I guess the difference arises not from using a method but from using variables vs. a constant 2**2 expression.

Comment: @luk2302 you're right! This is what was happening. However, there's still a question there: why does the type affect this? I mean, using variables or constants didn't affect in the case of `float`, but it did affect in the case of `int`. Do you know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

> Apparently, running something in a method can slow down your process depending on your data types, and that's really weird to me.

It would be really weird if it was not like this! You can write your class that has it's own `**` operator (through implementing the `__pow__(self, other)` method), and you could, for example, sleep 1s in there. Why should that take as long as taking a float to the power of another?

So, yeah, Python is a dynamically typed language. So, the operations done on data depend on the type of that data, and things can generally take different times.

In your first example, the difference never arises, because a) most probably the values get cached, because right after parsing it's clear that `2**2` is a constant and does not need to get evaluated every loop. Even if that's not the case, b) the time it costs to run a loop in python is hundreds of times that it takes to actually execute the math here – again, dynamically typed, dynamically named.

`base**exponent` is a whole different story. None about this is constant. So, there's actually going to be a calculation every iteration.

Now, the `**` operator (`__rpow__` in the Python data model) for Python's built-in `float` type is specified to do the float exponent (which is something implemented in highly optimized C and assembler), as exponentiation can elegantly be done on floating point numbers. Look for `nb_power` in cpython's `floatobject.c`. So, for the float case, the actual calculation is "free" for all that matters, again, because your loop is limited by how much effort it is to resolve all the names, types and functions to call in your loop. Not by doing the actual math, which is trivial.

The `**` operator on Python's built-in `int` type is not as neatly optimized. It's a lot more complicated – it needs to do checks like "if the exponent is negative, return a float," and it does not do elementary math that your computer can do with a simple instruction, it handles arbitrary-length integers (remember, a python integer has as many bytes as it needs. You can save numbers that are larger than 64 bit in a Python integer!), which comes with allocation and deallocations. (I encourage you to read `long_pow` in CPython's `longobject.c`; it has 200 lines.)

All in all, integer exponentiation is expensive in python, because of python's type system.